# Why can I not find all fields shown under "Manage form Display" under "Manage fields"?

Tags: 8, entities

When I try editing a content type in Drupal. I' can't see all the fields available under Manage Display in Manage fields? Is this a wanted behaviour or a bug?

Comment: fields that you created? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: No these where available before I took over editing the site? For example some are created ubercart and other plugins. So they might have been created by the plugin. I'm not sure about all fields though.

Comment: They could also be using Field Collections, try going to `/admin/structure/field_collections` and see if it exists.

Comment: No nothing there. I'm using D8 by the way.

Comment: Manage fields only shows fields that were added using configuration entities. Property fields & fake fields are not managed via the manage fields form.